# Scaled median shift between two observation when median is close to zero

Tags: normal-distribution, median, scoring-rules

I'm coming for a computer science background and statistics is not my forte, please bear with me.

I have two revisions $R_1$ and $R_2$ each consisting of around 10000 processes $T_i$ (involving some sensor readings). In each process we make $n$ observations (i.e., for each $i$ in either revisions we have a vector $T_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$). We assume these vectors exhibit normal/Gaussian distributions.

Here is our challenge: between each revisions for almost all processes, we see shift/changes/deviations in the observations. This could be due to changes in the environment, sensor readings, setup parameters, etc.. My job is to identify and mark those observations that require further analysis. In other words, $i$ is "interesting" if $T_{i,R_1}$ and $T_{i,R_2}$ *differ* to a degree that requires human check.

What I want to do is to assign a score to each $i$ and report top 100 or so. One of our scores is shift in the median between $R_1$ and $R_2$ for every $T_i$. The problem is the median of $T_i$ and $T_j$ could be significantly different in magnitude and this would skew the score towards processes with larger median. A workaround is to scale the delta of two medians by the median of $T_{i,R_1}$, that is

$$
score = \frac{\text{median}(T_{i,R_1}) - \text{median}(T_{i,R_2})}{\text{median}(T_{i,R_1})}.
$$

In this case, however, we have a bias towards the processes that have median near zero. It breaks altogether if median is exactly zero (which does happen).

My question is, how can I implement a score that compares the (shift between) medians of two datasets. More generally, how does one compare the changes between two empirical observations and mark "large" changes?

Comment: For the question "how do I compare two distributions with different scales?" you might try normalization of the data. For the question "how do I mark 'large' changes?" that is a different can of worms, we need context.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. What kind of context do you need? As I mentioned I'm quite novice so a bit of pointers for context would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a score of either
$$\frac{a-b}{|a|+|b|}
\ \text{ or }\
\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the medians.

If $a$ and $b$ are both zero you can assign a score of zero. That is the only case in which a zero denominator would give you trouble, so this should work reasonably in all the cases of interest to you.